# How can I use mjpeg_server package?

Tags: ros, mjpeg-server, ros-kinetic, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

So I am really new to ROS. and I m trying to use the image/video that mjpeg_server(or ros_web_video) gets from a topic I created to my own HTML page not the default one that the package uses. I need only the image. I tried directly grabbing it from the link but i get in my browser's console couldn't connect to 8080 (maybe because I m already connected to an other websocket that i launched with rosbridge pkg which uses port 9090). I am using ROS Kinetic with Ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331377/how-can-i-use-mjpeg_server-package-?/) by [WhatWhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/45056/whatwhat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I figured it out. i used the web_video_server package to do it. At first I used an `<iframe>` to display the video feed in my html page which doesn't work. However using an `<img>` with the second URL that I overlooked works. the URL I used is in the [package wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/web_video_server) under 2.1 Available URLs.
So at the end i got something like this:
`<img src="https://localhost:8080/stream?topic=/camera/rgb/image_raw">`

---

Originally posted by [WhatWhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/45056/whatwhat/) with karma: 16 on 2019-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0